# Write contents of List<string> into a text file

Tags: c#

I have a program that checks two text files for a specific field then checks to see if either file has the specified field. If it does then the number of matches is stored into another List. The problem I am having is that it is only writing the first match to the text file, when I know I have two matches. I am fairly new to C# so any help/advice would be appreciated, the code below is doing the check.

```
while ((lineBeingRead = fileToRead.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (lineBeingRead.IndexOf("       :22:", 0) == 0)
    {
        lstTwentyOneCounter.Add(lineBeingRead.Substring(11));
        lstStoreTwentyOne = lstTwentyOneCounter;
    }
}
```

The code below is writing to the text file.

```
foreach (var single103 in lstStore103)
{
    foreach (var single101 in lstStore101)
    {
        if (single101 == single103)
        {
            checkResults.Add(single103);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"H:\Compare.txt", single103);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: See: [System.IO.File.WriteAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd383463.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WriteAllText` will [overwrite](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext(v=vs.110).aspx) the existing file - so only a single entry will appear to be written.

You will want to [append](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendalltext(v=vs.110).aspx) or [write all](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd383463.aspx) instead.

```
System.IO.File.Delete(@"H:\Compare.txt");

foreach (var single103 in lstStore103)
{
    foreach (var single101 in lstStore101)
    {
        if (single101 == single103)
        {
            checkResults.Add(single103);
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"H:\Compare.txt", single103 + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
}
```

or (if neither `lstStore103` nor `lstStore101` have duplicates):

```
System.IO.File.Delete(@"H:\Compare.txt");

foreach (var value in lstStore103.Intersect(lstStore101))
{
    checkResults.Add(value);
    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"H:\Compare.txt", value + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that has fixed it, I know it needs to be refactored and cleaner but for now it works so I am happy :)

Comment: @RyanK Be sure to upvote Tim's answer as well (the up arrow on the left side of his post).

Answer (score 2):

The `break;` is responsible, it will leave the loop.
But you also don't want to use `WriteAllText` which rewrites the whole text-file but you want to append a new line. I would use this approach:

```
string startPattern = "       :22:";
List<string> lstStoreTwentyOne = File.ReadLines(path)
    .Where(l => l.StartsWith(startPattern))
    .Select(l => l.Substring(startPattern.Length))
    .ToList();
```

This will create and fill the list. I don't know how this is related to the `lstStore103`-list.

However, this will write all to the text-file and replaces your loops:

```
var matchingItems = lstStore103.Intersect(lstStore101);
File.WriteAllLines(@"H:\Compare.txt", matchingItems);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Tim it is really helpful, I have accepted mjwillis as the answer as for now this works to suite my needs but I will definitely use yours when I come to refactor the code, again appreciate the help.